# I have to restore system to bios default before the system will locate wifi

Tags: networking

My wifi doesn't work unless I go to f2 and reset to the Bios default.  How do I fix it so it will enable wifi without having to go to setup

Comment: You didn't give us a whole lot of information to go on. What version Ubuntu? What wireless card/dongle? What drivers? Try turning `secure boot` on/off in the BIOS.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.  I will remember that for next time.  Going to secure boot and disabling it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: To accept my answer, please click on the grey checkmark icon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the comments...

Disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS fixed the problem with the wireless driver.